# How define a method generation receiving variadic arguments

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In a ruby class definition, I want to define a method generator. Say us that every method that I want to generate differs in a symbol and the number of parameters. So, I have something like this:

```
def self.my_define_service1(name) # generate for 1 parameter
    define_method(name) do |p1|
      # basic stuff
      call(name.intern, p1)
    end
end

def self.my_define_service2(name) # generate for 1 parameter
    define_method(name) do |p1, p2| 
      # basic stuff
      call(name.intern, p1,p2)
    end
end

# and so on ... many definitions as the number of parameters I have
```

`call` is a method kind of dispatcher which receives a symbol name and the parameters.

My question is: is it possible to write only a generator? Something like that

```
def self.my_define_service(name, *args)
    define_method(name) do |args| # <-- how to do here?
      # basic stuff
      call(name.intern, *args)
    end
end
```

and if the answer is affirmative, how?

Comment: What does `|p1}` do?

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a lot easier with `eval`:

```
def self.my_define_service(name, *args)
    pars_list = args.join ', '
    d = %{
          def #{name}(#{pars_list})
            call(':#{name}', #{pars_list})
          end
        }
    eval d
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
def self.my_define_service(name, *args)
  define_method(name) do |*args|
    # basic stuff
    call(name.intern, *args)
  end
end
```